# How can I store cookies in react's port i.e. 3000 from my express server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cookies

I am trying to store jwt token into httpOnly cookie. My Express server is running on port 5000 and the react development server is running on port 3000. When a user attempts to login from the route ('/login'), the cookie is not stored in the port 3000 i.e. on my react app there is no cookie.
How can I store thise cookie into my react app which runs on port 3000 from my express server which runs on port 5000?
I will be very happy if somebody helps me.

This is how I have stored the token into httpOnly cookie from login.js file

```
            res.cookie('access_token', JSON.stringify(token), {
                secure: true,
                httpOnly: true,
                expires: new Date(Date.now() + (60 * 24 * 360000)),
            })
            res.send('Cookie have been saved successfully');
```

When I visit '/login' route in react app then cookies stored shows as zero.

[this is when it shows when I go to cookies section in the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RbrY2.png)

Comment: Your cookie has `secure: true`, which means that it is set only over HTTPS. But your frontend URL has HTTP, not HTTPS.